# How do I update compiler for embark?

Tags: solidity, compiler, embark

I am rewriting an old contract I had. I am using the latest version of OZ contracts.. but they require:

`pragma solidity ^0.6.2`

I am using embark 5.2.3 and current compiler is 0.6.1+commit.e6f7d5a4.Emscripten.clang

So, how do I update the compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.. pretty easy.
Simply change the version in embark.json